# JQuery can't access new element after Ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form with several *select* inputs which are reloaded by Ajax when I changed a Date field. I want to keep the current selections when ajax reloads the *select* elements, but when I try to get them once the ajax function has reloaded the *select* elements I only get "*Undefined*".

The *select* objects are reloaded correctly using Ajax functions, but the problem is that I'cant keep the current selections.

I've defined the jQuery change event's handler of "#myDate" field on **$(document).on**.

```
$(document).on('change', '#myDate', function(e){ 
    callAjaxSelectClient( $("#idCity").val(), $('#idClientOpt option:selected').val());
    callAjaxSelectLuggage( $("#idCity").val(), $('#luggageOpt option:selected').val());     
});
```

I show you the ajax call (one example, all calls are similar). I send two parameters, *idCity* which it's a fix value, and the current selection of *idClientOpt* to keep it selected when the ajax call rewrites it.

```
function callAjaxSelectClient( idCity, idClientOpt )    {

            var params = {
                    "idCity" : idCity,
                    "idClientOpt" : idClientOpt,
            };

            $.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    data:  params,
                    url:   'ajax/reload.client.php',
                    type:  'post',
                    success:  function (response) {
                            $("#div-client").html(response);
                    }
            });
    }
```

The function calls "ajax/reload.client.php", which writes the html select code generate this code:

```
<select name="idClient" id="idClient">
    <option value="1">Miguel Cervantes</option>
    <option value="2">William Shakespeare</option>
    <option value="3">George Orwell</option>
</select>
```

Thanks,
Cheers

Comment: Is the `<select>` placed inside `$("#div-client")` ?

Comment: You need to set global variables and then backup your current form data and repopulate after the form content is replaced by ajax. You can try using ajax if the form is too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! the code is correct, the problem was on the ID of my select fields which I reload by Ajax ("*idClient*" instead "*idClientOpt*"), so when I tried to get the value of the new select reloaded, I didn't found it..

Thanks by your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
bindAjaxSelectChange();

function callAjaxSelectClient( idCity, idClientOpt ) {
        var params = {
                "idCity" : idCity,
                "idClientOpt" : idClientOpt,
        };

        $.ajax({
                async: true,
                data:  params,
                url:   'ajax/reload.client.php',
                type:  'post',
                success:  function (response) {
                        $("#div-client").html(response);

                        bindAjaxSelectChange();
                }
        });
}

function bindAjaxSelectChange() {
        $(document).unbind('change').on('change', '#myDate', function(e) { 
                callAjaxSelectClient($("#idCity").val(), $('#idClientOpt option:selected').val());
                callAjaxSelectLuggage($("#idCity").val(), $('#luggageOpt option:selected').val());     
        });
}
```

Basically, dynamically added elements are not respected by existing event handlers so we need to rebind the event after every change. Notice the ".off('change')" - we're removing the old handler before anything else.

Comment: Thanks by your reply, but the behavior is not the expected!! If I use .off("change") the ajax function is not called when I change #myDate field.

Comment: Try `$(document).unbind('change').on('change', '#myDate', function(e) {`

Comment: Now the ajax function is called each time I change #myData, but it doesn't keep my current selection

Answer (score 0):

To solve this keep hidden
 in view page.

and load only ooption from callAjaxSelectClient function.

OR

you need to load jquery.js with ajax/reload.client.php

Comment: Thanks PraveenD. I don't understand your first suggestions, only load option? i need the select complete, but with the current selection. The second suggetion doesn't work :(

Comment: what version of jquery you are using? user 1.7 or above.

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.11.2

Answer (score 0):

You can save form data to a global JSON variable and repopulate.

**Note** : You need to make proper adjustments based on your situation.

```
<script>
  var $data = [];

  function callAjaxSelectClient(idCity, idClientOpt) {
      var params = {
          "idCity": idCity,
          "idClientOpt": idClientOpt,
      };
      $data = $("form#form_id").serializeObject();
      $.ajax({
          async: true,
          data: params,
          url: 'ajax/reload.client.php',
          type: 'post',
          success: function(response) {
              $("#div-client").html(response);
              repopulateForm();
          }
      });
  }

  //Create JSON from form.
  $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
      var o = {};
      var a = this.serializeArray();
      $.each(a, function() {
          if(o[this.name]) {
              if(!o[this.name].push) {
                  o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
              }
              o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
          } else {
              o[this.name] = this.value || '';
          }
      });
      return o;
  };

  //Populate form
  repopulateForm = function() {
      $.each($data, function(name, val) {
          var $el = $('[name="' + name + '"]'),
              type = $el.attr('type');
          switch(type) {
              case 'checkbox':
                  $el.attr('checked', 'checked');
                  break;
              case 'radio':
                  $el.filter('[value="' + val + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
                  break;
              default:
                  $el.val(val);
          }
      });
  }
</script>
```